# Mismatched types on custom error

Tags: anchor, rust, error-handling

I'm getting this error on build when trying to apply custom errors:

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> programs/auc/src/lib.rs:27:20
   |
27 |             return err!(MyError::NotAdmin);
   |                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected enum `anchor_lang::prelude::ProgramError`, found enum `anchor_lang::error::Error`
   |
   = note: this error originates in the macro `anchor_lang::error` (in Nightly builds, run with -Z macro-backtrace for more info)
```

I believe I applied it exactly as in the [documentation](https://www.anchor-lang.com/docs/errors)  :

```
   if campaign.admin != *user.key {
            return err!(MyError::NotAdmin);
        }
...

#[error_code]
pub enum MyError {
    #[msg("You are not the admin of this campaign.")]
    NotAdmin
}
```

Does anybody know what I did wrong?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following code snippet illustrates the implementation of custom errors within a program.

```
use anchor_lang::prelude::*;    
declare_id!("Fg6PaFpoGXkYsidMpWTK6W2BeZ7FEfcYkg476zPFsLnS");

#[program]
pub mod flipper2 {
    use super::*;

    pub fn errorise(_ctx: Context<Errorise>) -> Result<()> {
        if true {
            return Err(MyError::NotAdmin.into());
        }
        Ok(())
    }
}

#[derive(Accounts)]
pub struct Errorise<'info> {
    #[account(mut)]
    pub user: Signer<'info>,
}

#[error_code]
pub enum MyError {
    #[msg("You are not the admin of this campaign.")]
    NotAdmin,
}
```

Comment: WHen I try that it gives me this error:

the trait bound `anchor_lang::prelude::ProgramError: std::convert::From<MyError>` is not satisfied

the trait `std::convert::From<MyError>` is not implemented for `anchor_lang::prelude::ProgramError`

help: the following other types implement trait `std::convert::From<T>`:

Comment: Maybe there was a missing whitespace in the line that I've written.

Comment: Excuse me, your code works.  The problem is that my function has a programresult output:
   pub fn close(ctx: Context<Close>) -> ProgramResult {
....  And the rest of my code does not work when I use Result...

Comment: Excuse me, your code works.  The problem is that my function has a programresult output, which was deprecated a couple versions ago.  Thank you sir!